# Does a nuget project need a nuget.config file

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

I am new to nuget packages. I am trying to create a nuget package with VSTS.
I am getting an error
"No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at D:\a\r1\a\Nuget\tempNuGet_1032.config"

Now I donot have a nuget.config file in my project.
Do I need to add one? What is the use of nuget.config file?

Comment: Which task did you use to create the package?

Comment: @ Eddie, Nuget Pack

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to *create* a NuGet package from your own code, you do **not** need a `NuGet.config` file.

The `NuGet.config` file exists to specify package sources from which packages are *installed* and *updated* - i.e. where you *consume* packages from.
Typically this is nuget.org - in which case, you don't have to include the file, because nuget.org is included in the computer wide setting found in `NuGetDefault.Config`. [You can read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Where creating you own NuGet package, you need to provide some metadata that describes, names and versions the package. You have two options to do so:

1) Include the information in the .csproj file [using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio) or [adding the information manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli) in the .csproj file

2) [Add a separate .nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec)

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. This answers my question about the nuget.config.Do you have any idea about the error I am getting when I try to push my package using azure devops?

Comment: Where are you building? On a Microsoft Hosted Agent (in that case, which one?) or on a Self Hosted Agent?

Comment: I am using Hosted VS2017.

Comment: Have you had a look at the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/nuget?view=vsts&tabs=designer#create-a-nuget-package

Comment: Yes, The nuget pack is the same. But for the nuget push when I add the nuget path as mentioned in the doc I get error saying, no package matching the search pattern, so no package is pushed. So I added the path to be `**/ProjectName*.nupkg` which works fine and pushes the package to the feed, but gives the above error. FYI the nuget push step is in Release pipeline for me rather than build pipeline.